# In ggplot, how can I set ylim and also lower the histogram to the x-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, yaxis

I have a number of histograms created in ggplot2. In some of them, the highest value touches the upper part of the frame. I would like to have a little space between the tallest bin and the frame. I know I can change the upper limit manually with ylim but I am finding a conflict with the scale_y_continuous() command. Here's the analogous problem using the iris data.

Simple plot

```
ggplot(iris,aes(Sepal.Length)) + geom_histogram()
```

Drop the histogram down to the x-axis

```
ggplot(iris,aes(Sepal.Length)) + geom_histogram() + 
scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0,0))
```

Change the upper limit of the y-axis

```
ggplot(iris,aes(Sepal.Length)) + geom_histogram() + 
scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0,0)) + ylim(0,15)
```

Now, the histogram is no longer sitting on the x-axis. It appears that the scale_y_continuous() command is switched off by ylim(). Is there a way around this conflict? Is there a way to set the upper limit of ylim with an arithmetic expression like adding 5 to the maximum bin height?

Comment: You can use the `limits` argument within `scale_y_continuous`.  Also, the development version of *ggplot2* has allowed for asymmetrical expansion of limits. An example is in the github [NEWS](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/NEWS.md), which looks similar to what is in [this thread](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1669#issuecomment-256653026)

Comment: `ggplot(iris,aes(Sepal.Length)) + geom_histogram() + 
scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0.5))` Is this what you want?

Comment: Your code does not place the histogram directly on the x-axis (there is gray space below the histogram).  Your advice about using limits within scale_y_continuous is spot on. Thanks to your tip, here is the code that works for my dual needs:                              
       ggplot(iris,aes(Sepal.Length)) + geom_histogram() + 
       scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),limits=c(0,15))